# Use python3 pickle to serialize custom object from and unserialize it in python2

Tags: python, pickle, numpy-ndarray

I have a script, that runs in python3 needs to open a function "fbp" that runs only in python2. For that I use execnet. Since the "fbp" function needs certain inputs, which I want to hand over from the python3 script I serialize it by using pickle:

```
import pickle
import base64

a = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(input, protocol=2, fix_import=True))
```

Where input is a list of objects of the class Image.
Then I hand it over to the python2 script:

```
def call_python_version(version, argument_list):
  gw = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=python%s" % version)
  channel = gw.remote_exec("""
     import sys
     from reco_FBP import fbp
     channel.send(fbp(*channel.receive()))
   """)
  channel.send(argument_list)
  return channel.receive()

b = call_python_version('2.7', [a])
```

In the python2 function I now try to decode the serialized input with:

```
def fbp(input):
  input_list = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(input))
  fbp = reconstruct(input_list)
  return fbp
```

But I get the following error message:

```
  corrected_list = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(corrected_list))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
  return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
  dispatch[key](vector://vector/webapp/self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1089, in load_newobj
  obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
AttributeError: class Image has no attribute '__new__'
```

I don't know how to fix this error. I already searched quite a lot but importing the class file didn't help. I also tried to save the input as numpy array and then load it with np.load() but this results in a pickle error since the python3 version saves the array with pickle protocol 3 which python2 cannot understand.

Edit:
changed `pickle.dumps()` to `pickle.loads()` and `base64.b64encode` to `base64.b64decode` in `fbp()`

Comment: The `fbp` function you show does `pickle.dumps(base64.b64encode(input))` (encode + dump) that doesn't make much sense. You want the exact opposite which is `pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(input))` (**decode** + **load**). Also note that there are limits to the amount of data that can be stored in a single command line parameter, so it could get truncated. I wouldn't recommend doing things as you are right now. Just store the pickled data in a temporary file with `pickle.dump`.

Comment: Thank you, that was of course not intended. I corrected it. I tried to use `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()` but the problem still exists. I will nevertheless change it to make it more stable.

Comment: You are still doing `pickle.loads(base64.b64encode(input))` which is wrong. You want `pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(input))` (notice the **`b64decode`**).

Comment: Ahh yes sorry, I changed that too. The error ist still present.

Comment: Does your `Image` class inherit from `object`? Try making it so.

Comment: https://github.com/Doist/pickle-compat collects some quirks to care about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marco Bonelli and @tevemadar I could solve the problem. It is caused through the differences of class inheritance in python2 and python3. Since I have no rights to edit the class, I used `pickle-compat` and simply added it in my python2 script:

```
import pickle-compat

pickle_compat.patch()

def fbp(input):
  input_list = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(input))
  fbp = reconstruct(input_list)
  return fbp
```

Now I can load the files without an error.
See: https://github.com/Doist/pickle-compat